# Which user launched EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have some EC2 instances that I don't really know who launched them.

Is there a way to know who launched a specific instance?

Comment: There is no way to find out who launched the instance. I am also looking for this feature.

Comment: Do you have any reference on that?

Comment: I have read the [EC2 API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) numerous times. I found that there is no EC2 API which exposes this information. Hence I could not pull this info from Console/CLI/SDKs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately this information is not directly available via an API call - you currently have two options:

1. depending on your needs, you could approximate your goal by using the [DescribeInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html) API action to look at the `key-name` used for starting that instance (if any, it's optional, though usually in place) - assuming you have followed security best practices and are using a dedicated EC2 key pair per [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) user (rather than sharing keys), the key should usually denote the user who started the instance ;)

   - that's most easily tested via the [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), specifically [describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)
2. nowadays you could activate [AWS CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/), which *records AWS API calls for your account and delivers log files to you* and **provides exactly the information you are after**:

> The recorded information includes the identity of the API caller, the
>   time of the API call, the source IP address of the API caller, the
>   request parameters, and the response elements returned by the AWS
>   service.
>   
>   AWS CloudTrail is a long overdue and invaluable tool and provides unprecedented insight into your AWS usage; it is easy to [get started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/getting_started_top_level.html) and only has a few remaining caveats currently:

- most importantly, it isn't available in all regions yet, but AWS has just extended it to 3 more for a total of 5, see [AWS CloudTrail Expands Again - More Locations and Services](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudtrail-expansion/), thus quickly approaching coverage of their entire [Global Infrastructure](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/globalinfrastructure/)
- not all services are covered yet, but AWS hast just extended it to 7 more for a total of 15, see [AWS CloudTrail Update - Seven New Services](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloudtrail-update-new-services-support-from-cloudcheckr/)
- depending on your needs, you most likely want to have a [Logging as a Service (LaaS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logging_as_a_Service_%28LaaS%29) solution in place to ease digging through the vast amount of logs, and provide alerts etc. - several providers already offer dedicated CloudTrail integration (and usually a free tier sufficient for that as well)
- events are delivered *within 15 minutes of the API call* and the resulting logs *to your S3 bucket approximately every 5 minutes*, resulting in a maximum delay of 20 minutes, which is enough for post hoc and batch analysis, but not sufficient for near real-time alerting of course (see the [AWS CloudTrail FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/faqs/))

Comment: very nice answer. i recently discovered CloudTrail and I totally agree.

Comment: CloudTrail track all the API activities with `Event time`, `User name`, `Event name`, `Resource type`, `Resource name`.

Comment: For the first approach, if you are using the JSON output, look for `KeyName`. Command `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-foobar123 --profile your_profile | grep "KeyName"`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have configured CloudTrail already in your console (to monitor the right events) here's a possible solution to retrieve the username of who launched a certain EC2 instance, given the instance ID.

This solution uses the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudtrail/lookup-events.html) to retrieve information about which instances were launched, and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) for parsing.

---

When calling the `aws cloudtrail lookup-events` function, we can specify:

- The name of the event. In this case, *RunInstances*.
- The date from which to start searching, *start-date*. This can be when the EC2 instance was launched.
- The date up to which to search, *end-date*. This can be just one minute after the instance was started.

First, let's define the instance id and the region variables:

```
$ instance_id="i-08dcc12c018737061"
$ region="us-east-1"
```

then, let's find out when the instance was launched:

```
$ instance_launch_date=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $instance_id --region $region | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].LaunchTime')
$ echo $instance_launch_date
"2020-07-08T15:21:02.000Z"
```

now, let's sanitize the date so that it's in the right format for the CloudTrail API.

```
$ launch_date=$(sed -E 's/\"([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}).+/\2\/\3\/\1 \4:\5:\6/' <<< $instance_launch_date)
$ start_date=$(date -d "${launch_date}" +"%s")
$ echo $start_date
1594221662
```

now, let's define the end date as the date the instance was launched plus 1 minute:

```
$ end_date=$(date -d "${launch_date} 1 min" +"%s")
echo $end_date
1594221722
```

and now let's call the CloudTrail API, and filter the output with `jq`:

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=RunInstances --start-time $start_date --end-time $end_date --region $region | jq --arg INSTANCE_ID "$instance_id" '.Events[] | select(.CloudTrailEvent | fromjson | .responseElements.instancesSet.items[].instanceId | contains($INSTANCE_ID)) | .Username '
"paolo"
```