# Is it possible to create an AWS IAM policy for automatic resource tagging?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I would like to set up different [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) users so that if an AWS resource is created by that IAM user, the resource is automatically assigned a specific tag.

For example: if IAM user F creates a new EC2 instance, the instance is automatically tagged as User:MrF. Is it possible to build a custom policy that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not available when using the AWS APIs directly (i.e. there's no way to command all AWS API's to tag new resources automatically on your behalf), however, depending on the specifics of your use case you could work around that limitation by correlating the creating user with the resource via post hoc tagging:

### Workaround

You could activate [AWS CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/), which *records AWS API calls for your account and delivers log files to you* and provides exactly the information you are after:

> The recorded information includes the identity of the API caller, the
>   time of the API call, the source IP address of the API caller, the
>   request parameters, and the response elements returned by the AWS
>   service.

Based on that information, a dedicated service of yours could analyze the logs and apply post hoc tags to all resources based on the logged user and created resource via the resp. API actions. Please see my answer to [Which user launched EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23494825/45773) for some caveats/constraints to consider when going down this route.

Answer (score 6):

My company GorillaStack have an open source lambda function that does exactly that.

The function 'listens' for CloudTrail logs to be delivered and tag the created resource with the ARN of the user that created it.  It also support cross account tagging, for cases where a central account collects CloudTrail logs for other accounts.

- Github: https://github.com/GorillaStack/auto-tag
- Blog Post: http://blog.gorillastack.com/gorillastack-presents-auto-tag

It got a shout out at the 2015 re:Invent conference which is pretty cool :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm about to test this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An even better solution (faster plus I believe cheaper than parsing through CloudTrail logs) is to use CloudTrail but in combination with **CloudWatch Events**.

[This is the basic concept described in a diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8tOD.png)

The implementation is detailed in this article:
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx150Z810KS4ZEC/How-to-Automatically-Tag-Amazon-EC2-Resources-in-Response-to-API-Events

The article also describes how to setup an IAM policy that only allows the creator of a resource to perform certain actions (like start / stop, describe, edit, terminate) against it.

Answer (score 1):

I would chose AWS Config. Create a rule that automatically tags resources on creation. No cost, works across multiple accounts. Great for enforcing compliance. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/03/aws-config-now-supports-tagging-of-aws-config-resources/

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such feature on IAM. If what you need is allow/deny based on user names, what you could do is use variables on your policy to allow or deny access based on naming conventions, e.g.:

```
...
"Resource":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-!:123456789:table/ItemsCatalog_${aws:username}"
...
```